# The job was not run

Tags: grammar

In the sentence “The job was not run.” (Computer job), why isn’t it “The job was not ran”?

What part of speech is “run”?

Comment: Please keep in mind that major English dictionaries often list the principal forms of verbs. For example, they might provide the bare infinitive form, third person singular indicative form, past tense form, and past participle form. You can then get this information yourself from a dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

*Run* is the past participle of the verb *run,* used as an adjective in a passive-voice construction.

Compare

- The house was not painted
- The offer was not accepted
- I was not punched

In all cases, the past participle is the form of the verb used for the present perfect ("have painted", "have accepted", "have punched").

*Ran* is the simple past of the verb *run,* and is used in sentences like "I ran the job"; "the job ran badly".

Comment: The migration was not unnoticed.